# Converting MATCH array formula to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to convert the formulas in a sheet into VBA code in a macro, and am stumped by the following:

`{=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A8&$B8&$C8&E$7,'Raw Data'!$E:$E&'Raw Data'!$D:$D&'Raw Data'!$C:$C&'Raw Data'!$G:$G,0)),"","Yes")}`

It's trying to look at multiple columns in one sheet, compare them to another, and see if the value of the column header is in the fourth column "G" to return "Yes" or blank. I've attached a screenshot of the sheet it fills out:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula will take a long time to compute, since each column has over one million rows. Array formulas should not use whole column references.

The same result can be returned with a non-array formula, which can be used in VBA without any special commands.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A8&$B8&$C8&E$7,Index('Raw Data'!$E$1:$E$1000&'Raw Data'!$D$1:$D$1000&'Raw Data'!$C$1:$C$1000&'Raw Data'!$G$1:$G$1000,0),0)),"","Yes")
```

If you want to use an array formula in VBA, you will need `.FormulaArray` instead of `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1`

If you don't want to enter a formula into a worksheet cell, but perform the calculation in VBA, you can use `Worksheetfunction` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) to use the worksheet functions and their syntax.